# Canonical ensemble: correlation function for quadratic potential energy

Tags: statistical-mechanics

In [this paper](http://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.91.060103) I can't understand the following

---

A given system has the potential energy
$
U(x_1,x_2,x_3)=k_1 x_1^2 + k_2 (x_2-x_1)^2 + k_3 x_3^2
$.
Since the energy is quadratic, the correlation matrix is given in terms of the Hamiltonian matrix $H$ by
$
<x_i x_j>  = k_BT (H^{−1})_{ij} \quad
$
 with
$
\quad H_{ij}=\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} \quad
$

Comment: shouldn't you also use kinetic energy in the partition function?

Comment: @tonydo That would only give you a multiplicative constant

Comment: I should write the sum as an integral instead maybe, I'll try a bit later

Comment: Ok so I used integrals instead as the variables are continuous (edit). I get something that looks like the expected result but I still miss something.

Comment: I have something which can relate your edit with the $(H^{-1})_{ij}$ matrix. Why did you erase it? If it was wrong, post a correct version and that maybe help with my calculus (which may be wrong, of course ^^")

Comment: @V_Programmer I think I was editing when you commented. I finally found the answer so I posted the answer myself.  The journey was unexpected long, but maybe I took a unnecessary long way? Thank you for your interest :)

Comment: I found a derivation and posted it. Is it find to answer to your own question? Let my know the etiquette please

Comment: Answering your own question is great.

Comment: @David I did exactly the same you did, but I didn't know about the existence of the Jacobi identitiy. What I used is that $H_{ij}$ is symmetric, so you can diagonalice it. Then you can write the determinant as the product of the elements, work a bit, and using that in a diagonal matrix ${(H^{-1})}_{ij}={(H_{ij})}^{-1}$ you find the answer. But I think your way is better :)

Comment: So you did the same as me until $
<x_i x_j>=  k_BT \frac{\partial }{\partial H_{i,j}}(\ln(\det(H))
$ ?

And then you found a way around the Jacobi's formula?

Does it mean you basically demonstrated Jacobi's formula?

Answer (score 9):

A system is in a heat bath of temperature T so we work with the canonical ensemble. We consider $N$ degrees of freedom $x_1, x_2, ..., x_N$  and $x$ is the vector $(x_1~ x_2 ~ ... ~ x_N)^T$. The potential energy is quadratic so it can be expressed as a function of its second derivatives:

$
U=\sum_{i,j} x_i ~H_{i,j} ~x_j = x^T H x ~~
$
with $H_{i,j}=\frac{\partial^2 U}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}$.

$H$ is assumed invertible. 
The partition function $Z$ in the canonical ensemble is:

$
Z= \int (d^Nx)  ~  e^{ -\frac{1}{2} \beta x^T H x} ~ = ~ \sqrt{\frac{(2 \pi)^N}{\det(H)}}~~
$
 with $~~\beta=\frac{1}{k_BT}$,

where we used the multivariate Gaussian formula.

$
<x_i x_j> = \frac{1}{Z} \int (d^Nx)  ~ x_i x_j e^{ -\frac{1}{2} \beta x^T H x}
$

$
= \frac{1}{Z} (-\frac{2}{\beta})\frac{\partial}{\partial H_{i,j}}\int (d^Nx)  ~  e^{ -\frac{1}{2} \beta x^T H x}
$

$
= -2k_BT \frac{1}{Z} \frac{\partial Z}{\partial H_{i,j}}
$

$
=  -2k_BT \frac{\partial \ln(Z)}{\partial H_{i,j}}
$

We plug-in the expression of $Z$ that we found above:

$
<x_i x_j>=  k_BT \frac{\partial }{\partial H_{i,j}}(\ln(\det(H))
$

$H$ is invertible so we use Jacobi's formula:

$
\frac{\partial }{\partial H_{i,j}}(\ln(\det(H)) = Tr(H^{-1} \frac{\partial H}{\partial H_{i,j}})
$

$\frac{\partial H}{\partial H_{i,j}}$ is a matrix for which the element $\{i,j\}$ is $1$ and all other elements are $0$. In other words:

$
E\equiv \frac{\partial H}{\partial H_{i,j}}
$ with
$
E_{k,l}=\delta_{k,i} \delta_{l,j}.
$

$
Tr(H^{-1} \frac{\partial H}{\partial H_{i,j}}) = Tr(H^{-1}E)
$

$
(H^{-1}E)_{k,l}=\sum_m H^{-1}_{k,m}E_{m,l}=\sum_m H^{-1}_{k,m}\delta_{m,i}\delta_{j,l} = H^{-1}_{k,i} \delta_{j,l}
$

$
Tr(H^{-1} E)=\sum_n (H^{-1}E)_{n,n}=\sum_n H^{-1}_{n,i} \delta_{j,n} = H^{-1}_{j,i} = H^{-1}_{i,j}
$

and

$
<x_i x_j> = k_B T H^{-1}_{i,j}
$